# Is there any situation where the derivative ${ dy \over (dx)^2 }$ makes sense?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Is there any situation where the following expression ever make any sense in calculus?
${ dy \over (dx)^2 }$

If we imagine a square with side length $x$ and increase by a small amount $dx$, and $dy$ is the increase in area, then

$$dy = 2xdx+(dx)^2$$

Normally, the purpose is to calculate ${dy \over dx}=2x+dx = 2x$ by saying the extra $dx$ term is infinitesimal and can be treated as zero.

However, if we divide $(dx)^2$ instead we get

$${dy \over (dx)^2}={2x \over dx}+1$$

Now in this example the ${2x \over dx}$ term becomes infinity and therefore the expression makes no sense, but I am wondering is there any case that doing a similar thing would make sense and there is a meaning for the term ${ dy \over (dx)^2 }$.

It seems impossible to me at a glance for any expression to have a non-infinity term on the right, but once things get complicated and infinite series are involved I am wondering if it is really impossible or actually there is some field of study that the expression actually makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\frac{dy}{dx}$ is, by definition, the representation of how fast $y$ changes as $x$ changes, that is the *slope* of the graph at any point we are evaluating the derivative at. This slope could be a finite non-zero number, or zero, or $\infty$, or $-\infty$. You’re asking what the value of this slope times the reciprocal of an extremely small number is, i.e. $$\frac{dy}{dx} \times \frac{1}{dx} =\frac{dy}{dx} \times (\to \infty)$$

If $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is finite, or infinite, the answer is without a doubt infinite. If $\frac{dy}{dx} =0$, then you’re basically asking what $0 \times (\to \infty)$ is. The answer in this case would be **zero**.

Comment: Why would $0 \times \infty$ be 0? If $y = x^2$, then at $x=0$, you could interpret $dy/(dx)^2$ as $(dx)^2/(dx)^2 = 1$.

Comment: @Raoul Thank you for the example. Can you explain how ${dy \over (dx)^2} = {(dx)^2 \over (dx)^2} $ at $x=0$ and what does this mean in terms of speed of change at $x=0$?

Comment: @Raoul Because any number, no matter how large, multiplied by zero will always be zero. I’m not sure I get you, are you saying that at $x=0, dy= (dx)^2$?

Comment: The $dy$ and $dx$ should be understood as a limit. We classically have
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} = \lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{y(x) - y(x_0)}{x-x_0}.
$$
Similarly, it makes sense to understand OP's question as
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x^2} = \lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{y(x) - y(x_0)}{(x-x_0)^2},
$$
and if $y(x) = x^2$ and $x_0 = 0$, then this is indeed $1$. This means that if you change $x$ from $0$ to a tiny bit, $y$ changes to a tiny bit *squared*. More generally,$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x^2} = 2 y''(x_0)$ if $y'(x_0) = 0$, and $\pm \infty$ otherwise.

Comment: @Raoul You are claiming that $\frac ab = \frac cd$ implies $\frac {a}{b^2} = \frac{c}{d^2}$ which is clearly false. Also, the tiny change in $y$, $dy=2xdx$, not $(dx)^2$.

Comment: I did make a typo, $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x^2} = y''(x_0)/2$ if $y'(x_0) = 0$, but where am I using what you claim?

Comment: @Raoul Your first and second mathematical statement. Do you not consider $\frac {dy}{dx}$ a fraction?

Comment: I do, and I am saying $\mathrm{d}y = y(x) - y(x_0)$ and $\mathrm{d}x = x- x_0$. But the only rigorous way to make sense of that is to see it as a limit. $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}$ is not $\frac00$, but a limit. Similarly, $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x^2}$ should be understood as the limit I mention, not as $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} \times \frac{1}{\mathrm{d}x}$, which is something mysterious of the type $\frac00 \times \frac10$.

Comment: @Raoul I’m saying $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is of the **form** $\frac {\to 0}{\to 0}$, not equal to it. It is different depending on the function in context. Still not sure how $\frac{dy}{dx^2}$ equals the limit you mention, although writing it as $\frac{dy}{dx} \times \frac{1}{dx}$ makes complete sense, multiplying an infinite number with something that Is perfectly defined in itself.

Comment: But then, why do you interpret $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}$ as an indeterminate form $0/0$, but not $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x^2}$?.

Comment: @Raoul I do interpret it that way. The term $\frac 00$ is sort of ambiguous in itself. But I also interpret it equivalently as $\lim_{x\to. _0} a(x)\cdot b(x) =\lim_{x\to x_0} a(x) \ \lim_{x\to x_0} b(x)$ , where the limit of $a(x)$ is well-defined and of the form $\frac 00$ (analogous to $\frac{dy}{dx}$, whereas $b(x)$ plummets off to infinity (analogous to $\frac{1}{dx}$. Although the limit of their product is still of the form $\frac{0}{0}$, it is not a finite non-zero number.

Comment: You can write the product of the limits if they both exist, and in the case where the function has a nonzero derivative at $x_0$, then indeed, this is infinite. But when the derivative is $0$, as in the case I mention, you end up with a $0 \times \infty$ type of limit, which is not $0$ in general.

Comment: @Raoul I think you’re confusing $(\to 0)\times \infty$ with $0\times \infty$. When we are multiplying a number that is *exactly* $0$ to any number, don’t you think the result will be zero as well?

Comment: Yes, and it just loops back to my earlier comment: you are interpreting one of the elements as a limit, and the other as a fixed number, and I see no reason to do this. The quantity $0 \times \infty$ is not defined, as $\infty$ is not "any number". In essence, you are saying
$$
\lim_{x \to x_0} a(x) b(x) = lim_{x' \to x_0} \left ( \left ( \lim_{x \to x_0} a(x) \right ) b(x') \right ),
$$
which is not correct.

Comment: @Raoul I’m saying that $$\lim_{x\to x_0} a(x)b(x) = \lim_{x\to x_0} a(x) \ \lim_{x\to x_0} b(x)$$

Comment: Not when you are saying that $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x^2} = \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} \times \frac{1}{\mathrm{d}x} = 0 \times \infty = 0$.

Comment: @Raoul Why not? That’s exactly what’s used here.

Comment: Then why not say $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} =\mathrm{d}y \times \frac{1}{\mathrm{d}x} = 0 \times \infty = 0$?

Comment: I think the only unclear point here is about the case $0\times \infty$ which might make sense or not because the expression is ill-defined, but I can see this expression can hardly have useful meaning in any scenario based on the answer and discussion so far.

Comment: @Raoul Because $dy$ isn’t exactly zero in itself.

Comment: But $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}$ is exactly $0$? This means that you are taking partial limits in the expression $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x^2}$, as I explained above.

Comment: @cr001 Indeed, this would only make sense at points $x_0$ where $y'(x_0) = 0$. But there cannot be too many such points, except for a constant function, so there is no hope to define a useful *function* $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}$.

Comment: @Raoul Yes, that’s just the way I interpret it, although I agree that there’s no real significance to it.